# windows 8 phone app vs windows 8 tab app

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-phone-8

I am new to windows 8 app development I just want to know that it is possible to make one app package which will run both on windows tab and windows 8 phone [For example in case of iOS same ipa can be installed on iPhone as well as iPad]?

I know win 8 phone and win 8 tab/desktop have different sdks and and coding sharing can be possible. But can I make one common package to run it on both platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Xyroid explained they have different file name for apps. And since you compared to iOS, let me tell you that iPhone and iPad is basically the same device, with same architecture and same OS, with different screen resolution(if you ignore the calling function), so one IPA which works on iPhone, can work on iPad too.

While Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8 are two different OS, based on some common code and runtime, but they do actually have different app handling layers. They even have some different UI component. You can make a library (dll) which can work for both if it's just fetching data from a particular server or provides some low level functionality. But for creating single package which can run on both is a different thing. Even if they'd be using same file name, the internal codes and runtime can't be changed.

PS: WinRT apps can work on Windows 8 too, since WinRT is a stripped down version of Windows 8(without desktop app).

Answer (score 2):

No it's not possible. WP8 app packages are .XAP files & Windows 8 apps are .APPX/.APPXUPLOAD files. You can use various code sharing techniques like MVVM, PCL, etc, but you can't create a single file which acts as installer for both.

[Maximize code reuse between Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681693%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)